# Building wheel for pyproj (pyproject.toml) - Doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, pyproj, pyproject.toml

So im trying to install this package called etrago (https://pypi.org/project/eTraGo/). but it doesn't work. At the end I get something like this in my terminal:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyproj
Failed to build pyproj
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyproj, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have google this but sadly there is little to no info on the matter. Im using a Mac m1, python 3.10 and I tried install in a venv.

Can anybody here try it and tell me their experience ?
Thank you!

Comment: it probably doesn't have any wheels built for Mac M1, definitely not for Python 3.10 - it looks like the latest release (April 2021) just managed to get it compatible with Python 3.7

Comment: Seems to me like some details are missing... Is there more info in the terminal output? If not, then maybe you need to retry the same command with more verbose output (typically with the `--verbose` command flag).